# HP Proliant N40L windows 7 (64bit) driver?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, hp-proliant

I just installed windows 7 ultimate 64 bit into a new HP Proliant N40L. At the first glance, everything seems fine because device manager does not show any question mark on any device. However, there is no audio device and the video adapter is listed as "Standard VGA graphic adapter". Also only 16MB video memory is displayed in the advanced display property page, regardless of 128MB video memory settings in BIOS. When I try Media Player Classic with some MKV/mp4 files, the player pops a few error boxes regarding D3D device failure. The player will still play these files with poor FPS.

According to [this post](http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/hp-proliant-microserver-n40l-display-driver-for-windows-server-2008-r2/), the integrated graphic card is Radeon HD 4200 but after installing the latest software (about 150MB), windows still cannot see any additional hardware or graphic card.

Is there any problem in my installation?

UPDATE:

This box seems intended to be server because it even does not have on board audit port. Will wait to see if someone can clarify this and close this post.

Comment: Yes, HP ProLiant systems are intended to be used as servers, rather than as an HTPC (as it appears by your post).  The system you mentioned is an inexpensive microserver intended for SOHO applications.  I have not voted to close; this question isn't quite off topic for Super User.  If an expansion slot exists, you may want to purchase a sound card such as a Sound Blaster Audigy Value card.

Comment: Yes, it has two PCI slots. I have already started looking for sound card and graphics card.